# solution of the Bi-Laplace equation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I want to know the bi-Laplace equation with this two boundary conditions admits an unique solution in $H^2(\Omega)$, for given $h\in H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)$.

$$\Delta ^2 u=0,\quad on\quad \Omega, $$
$$\partial_n (\Delta u)\Big|_{\partial \Omega}=0,\qquad \Delta u\Big|_{\partial \Omega}=h,$$
where $\partial_n$ denotes the normal derivative, $n$ is the outward unit normal to $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: How do you understand these boundary conditions? Did you tried to write down a weak formulation (via integration by parts)?

Comment: @gerw, I can use the Green formula for the Bi-Harmonci equation in $ W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ as
$$\int_\Omega \Delta u \Delta v=\int_{\partial \Omega} h \frac{\partial v}{\partial n}, \qquad v\in W^{2,2}(\Omega), $$ this formulation is well defined...
But, it seems that $u+cst$, where $cst$ is a constant, is also a solution??

Comment: Yes, thus your problem is not uniquely solvable.